# MySQL sql_safe_updates ON does not allow LIKE in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```
mysql> show create table t1;
+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                          
+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the following data:

```
    mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| E001 | John  |
| E002 | Tom   |
| E003 | Fred  |
| E004 | Alice |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And MySQL safe updates set to ON:

```
mysql> show variables like "sql_safe_updates";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| sql_safe_updates | ON    |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following indexes on the table:

```
    mysql> show index from t1\G
*************************** 1. row **
        Table: t1
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 4
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following command works:

```
    mysql> UPDATE t1
    -> SET id = CONCAT("F-", id)
    -> WHERE id = "E002"
    -> OR id = "E003";
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1;
+--------+-------+
| id     | name  |
+--------+-------+
| E001   | John  |
| E004   | Alice |
| F-E002 | Tom   |
| F-E003 | Fred  |
+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now if the data in the table was changed back to the original:

```
    mysql> select * from t1;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| E001 | John  |
| E002 | Tom   |
| E003 | Fred  |
| E004 | Alice |
+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following command run:

```
    mysql> UPDATE t1
    -> SET id = CONCAT("F-", id)
    -> WHERE id LIKE "%2"
    -> OR id LIKE "%3";
ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE
that uses a KEY column
```

My question is why does the LIKE command fail when sql_safe_updates is ON, even though the column mentioned in the WHERE clause is an index (primary key)?

Comment: Mentioned != equal. Your primary key expression is NOT `id LIKE '%something'`. `WHERE id = ..` defines altered rows uniquely whereas `id LIKE ..` is not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the following query which worked:

mysql> UPDATE t1

     SET id = CONCAT("F-", id)

     WHERE id LIKE "E002"

     OR id LIKE "E003";

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

So it seems its more like MySQL doesn't equate the wildcard to an equals.
Do you have an more info/links on this as I still don't fully understand it.

Comment: *`sql_safe_updates` If this variable is enabled, UPDATE and DELETE statements that do not use a key in the WHERE clause or a LIMIT clause produce an error. This makes it possible to catch UPDATE and DELETE statements where keys are not used properly and that would probably change or delete a large number of rows. The default value is OFF.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates

Comment: This means that each condition expression and each its part must refer to columns which are indexed (separate or as a prefix). For example, if `WHERE val=5` is used then index by `(val)` or, for example, `(val, val2)`, allows safe update whereas by `(val2, val)` not allows. Any key (primary, unique, common) is enough.

Comment: But in my example `id` is an index (primary). `WHERE id LIKE "%2"` doesn't seem to recognise `id` an an index.
But `WHERE id LIKE "E%"` does allow the update.
According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-single-part the definition of a range on a WHERE clause includes LIKE except _if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character._

Comment: `WHERE id LIKE "%2"` cannot use index whereas `WHERE id LIKE "E%"` can. Like, for example, if `id` is not indexed and `val` is not then `WHERE id=1 AND val=1` is allowed but `WHERE id=1 OR val=1` is not... and so on.